# Heroku + Redis Cloud: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: heroku, redis, python-rq

I am using the Redis Cloud add-in on my Heroku application and I keep getting this error sporadically. I have tried flushing the redis DB and restarting dynos and that seems to fix it but I am curious why this is happening so often.

I am running worker dynos that use this redis DB and I am using python-rq to schedule jobs on the worker queues.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in connect
raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
2020-08-05T17:12:25.451733+00:00 app[worker_proc.5]: redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis-13618.c73.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13618. Temporary failure in name resolution.
2020-08-05 17:12:25,461 INFO exited: worker_proc-0 (exit status 1; not expected)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 559, in connect
sock = self._connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 584, in _connect
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(self.host, self.port, self.socket_type,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```